# Parallel HttpClient requests timing out due to async problem?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm running a method synchronously in parallel using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach`. At the end of the method, it needs to make a few dozen HTTP `POST` requests, which do not depend on each other. Since I'm on .NET Framework 4.6.2, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is exclusively asynchronous, so I'm using [`Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) to avoid deadlocks, in the form:

```cs
public static void MakeMultipleRequests(IEnumerable<MyClass> enumerable)
{
    AsyncContext.Run(async () => await Task.WhenAll(enumerable.Select(async c => 
        await getResultsFor(c).ConfigureAwait(false))));
}
```

The `getResultsFor(MyClass c)` method then creates an `HttpRequestMessage` and sends it using:

```cs
await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The response is then parsed and the relevant fields are set on the instance of MyClass.

My understanding is that the synchronous thread will block at `AsyncContext.Run(...)`, while a number of tasks are performed asynchronously by the single `AsyncContextThread` owned by `AsyncContext`. When they are all complete, the synchronous thread will unblock.

This works fine for a few hundred requests, but when it scales up to a few thousand over five minutes, some of the requests start returning `HTTP 408 Request Timeout` errors from the server. My logs indicate that these timeouts are happening at the peak load, when there are the most requests being sent, and the timeouts happen long after many of the other requests have been received back.

I think the problem is that the tasks are `await`ing the server handshake inside `HttpClient`, but they are not continued in FIFO order, so by the time they are continued the handshake has expired. However, I can't think of any way to deal with this, short of using a `System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim` to enforce that only one task can `await httpClient.SendAsync(...)` at a time.

My application is very large, and converting it entirely to async is not viable.

Comment: There isn't just black and white. Throttling down to 1 at a time would pretty much destroy your parallel approach. But throttling of some kind _is_ needed. What you are doing right now is basically a DoS attack.

Comment: The error is specifically a **client-side** 403 timeout, not a server-side 503 error. At peak I'm making a few thousand requests over five minutes, which is well within the server capacity. I have separate error handling code for the client to to handle server-side issues.

Comment: Yes, you _can_ DoS your own (local) network stack :) Solution is the same: tame your horses a bit. Maybe build batches or give some jitter offset time before starting ... or simply make sure there are less than X open requests at the same time. What X should _ideally_ be probably depends on the client system, though.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-make-concurrent-requests-with-httpclient/

Comment: @Fildor "making sure there are less than X open requests at the same time" - Unless I've misunderstood something, I don't think this can solve my problem (unless X == 1). Say there are 2 slots; what is to stop requests #2 through #200 passing through slot B while request #1 sits in slot A waiting to be continued, so when it is resumed it immediately times out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext` will execute on a threadpool thread; to avoid deadlocks in the way described requires an instance of `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContextThread`, as outlined in the [documentation](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncContext.md).

There are two possible causes:

- a bug in `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in .NET Framework 4.6.2
- the continuation priority issue outlined in the question, in which individual requests are not continued promptly enough and so time out.

As described at [this answer and its comments, from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21166666), it may be possible to deal with the priority problem using a custom `TaskScheduler`, but throttling the number of concurrent requests using a semaphore is probably the best answer:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nito.AsyncEx;

public class MyClass 
{
    private static readonly AsyncContextThread asyncContextThread
        = new AsyncContextThread();
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseMessage Response { get; private set; }
        
    private async Task GetResponseAsync()
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            Response = await httpClient.SendAsync(Request);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public static void MakeMultipleRequests(IEnumerable<MyClass> enumerable)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(enumerable.Select(c =>
            asyncContextThread.Factory.Run(() =>
                c.GetResponseAsync())).ToArray());
    }
}
```

---

*Edited to use `AsyncContextThread` for executing async code on non-threadpool thread, as intended. `AsyncContext` does not do this on its own.*

Comment: You don't need `async c => await c.GetResponseAsync()`. You could write just `AsyncContext.Run(Task.WhenAll(enumerable.Select(c =>c.GetResponseAsync())));`. Although all this code is no better than `Task.WaitAll(enumerable.Select(c =>c.GetResponseAsync())`, assuming `GetResponseAsync` uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally

Comment: The linked question says `use Dataflow` and only mentions `SemaphoreSlim` as an alternative

Comment: The linked question and answer are specifically about prioritising continuations; the answer _and its comments_ (as mentioned in this answer) advise that the best solution is throttling either with Dataflow or a semaphore. This answer uses a semaphore as it is far simpler and this problem doesn't need any of the features of Dataflow.

Comment: `AsyncContext.Run` takes a `Func<Task>` not a `Task`.

Comment: That's what I said, except the last part. I already posted the link to AsynContext's own code that shows what it does. To get back to the original thread, you have to keep it blocked. That thread is blocked, no matter what you use. And `Task.Wait` doesn't care about sync contexts at all. It already blocked the current context *and* its thread. What `AsyncContext` affects is the *await*ing in the tasks, if any. If there's no `await`, `AsyncContext` won't do anything. If you use `var tasks=urls.Select(url=>client.GetStringAsync(url));` for example, it won't do anything because there's no `await`

Comment: *"`Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext` does not execute on a non-threadpool thread"* <== @Simon that's a bit confusing, because of the double negative. Do you mean that `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext` executes exclusively on `ThreadPool` threads, and it will deny execution if the [`Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isthreadpoolthread) property is `false`?

Comment: The intention is to solve deadlocks which may occur if all threadpool threads are blocked at `Task.WaitAll` waiting for async continuations. `AsyncContextThread` solves this as it uses a single non-threadpool thread to execute the async work. `AsyncContext` (used in the original version of this question) doesn't address this, as @PanagiotisKanavos states above - it uses regular threadpool threads for execution. I don't think it specifically checks them though.

Comment: AFAIK the `AsyncContext.Run` uses the current thread as a context, and it doesn't care if the current thread is owned by the `ThreadPool`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something that can be done with wrapping the tasks before blocking. For starters, if the requests go through, you may end up nuking the server. Right now you're nuking the client. There's a 2 concurrent-request per domain limit in .NET Framework that can be relaxed, but if you set it too high you may end up nuking the server.

You can solve this by using DataFlow blocks in a pipeline to execute requests with a fixed degree of parallelism and then parse them. Let's say you have a class called `MyPayload` with lots of `Items` in a property:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;

var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
};

var downloader=new TransformBlock<string,MyPayload>(async url=>{
    var json=await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
    var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPayload>(json);
    return data;
},options);

var importer=new ActionBlock<MyPayload>(async data=>
{
    var items=data.Items;
    
    using(var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var bcp=new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    using(var reader=ObjectReader.Create(items))
    {
        bcp.DestinationTableName = destination;
        connection.Open();

        await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
    }
});


downloader.LinkTo(importer,new DataflowLinkOptions { 
    PropagateCompletion=true
});
```

I'm using [FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) to wrap the items in a DbDataReader that can be used to bulk insert the records to a database.

Once you have this pipeline, you can start posting URLs to the head block, `downloader` :

```
foreach(var url in hugeList)
{
    downloader.Post(url);
}
downloader.Complete();
```

Once all URLs are posted, you tell `donwloader` to complete and await for the last block in the pipeline to finish with :

```
await importer.Completion;
```

Comment: I've already tried enforcing a limit on request parallelism using a `SemaphoreSlim`, as per the question. I don't think this solution would fix the issue of disordered async continuations causing timeouts - unless the enforced degree of parallelism is 1.

Comment: @SimonW it does, I'm using it to download 100K air ticket records per day for the last 6-7 years. This isn't enforcing parallelism. It's creatiing 10 worker tasks to process all the URLs posted to the block. That's *completely* different from starting 100 tasks and blocking 90 of them. Besides, in .NET Framework only 2 concurrent requests are allowed at a time. By changing `DefaultConnectionLimit` it's possible to make up to 1000 requests. `MaxDOP=10` though ensures only 10 URLs will be processed at a time

Comment: @SimonW it's also possible to  further throttle requests by adding `await Task.Delay()` in the worker method. To avoid sending requests in waves, the delay can be randomized.

Comment: As I understand it, this will attempt to process 10 requests asynchronously; send #1, then while awaiting its return, send #2, and so on. There is no guarantee that request #1 will be continued soon after its server handshake returns, instead of the single available thread choosing to continue various awaits encountered in requests #2 through #10 first - and when request #1 is finally continued, it times out. The only way to fix this with Dataflow would be to only allow one request at a time, which is identical to throttling with a semaphore. Is my understanding of this incorrect?

Comment: @SimonW no. It will create 10 worker tasks and each one will process an input message. 10 threads will be processing messages at a time. Why would there be a timeout? Even if there is, it will affect the current task only and can be handled with a `try/catch` block. The other workers won't be affected. I've been using this to download air ticket sales reports with thousands of records each, parse them, forward the ticket numbers to a next step that retrieves individual ticket records.

Comment: @SimonW in one case, the web service is very unstable so I have to not only set a DOP but a delay as well to prevent multiple concurrent requests, otherwise the *service* crashes. It seems their load balancer sends all requests to the same 4 backend machines, which crash if too many requests are made. When that happens, it takes 3 minutes to restart the service *but the load balancer still uses the crashed service*, leading to even more errors. If what you claim were true I'd have no problem. A DOP of 4 *does* mean there are 4 concurrent requests though.

Comment: @SimonW you can verify what's going on if you use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what requests are actually made. If the DOP is N, you'll see N requests being made almost concurrently. You'll see that N requests are made more or less in waves, which could be a problem if the remote service can't handle all of them at once. You can spread them out a bit by adding a random delay before sending a request\

Comment: @SimonW you need to do that if you retry failed calls, either manually or using eg Polly. If the service failed with 30  concurrent requests and you retry all those after exactly 1 second, the service will crash again. Polly has a random retry delay to handle this

Comment: @SimonW the question says nothing about contexts, it talks about HttpClient with is *thread-safe* and *meant* to be reused by multiple threads. `Parallel.ForEach` uses multiple threads as well. What single-threaded context are you talking about?

Comment: (sorry, missed your reply) Perhaps you missed the part about `AsyncContext` and its single `AsyncContextThread`?

Comment: That's how you attempted to solve the problem. It didn't work though, and the system crashes during peak traffic.

Comment: @SimonW on the other hand, 408 is sent when the server closes an idle connection. Are you sure you really have a throttling issue? Perhaps you're leaking connections? How are you using HttpClient? Typically, you should be using a single instance. This will cache and reuse socket connections, eliminating the DNS resolution step. At some point those sockets will be closed *by the client itself*

Comment: As stated in the question, the `AsyncContext` is used to call asynchronous code from synchronous code. This is required since all `HttpClient` methods are asynchronous. I'm not aware of any guaranteed non-deadlocking alternatives to this approach.

Comment: I just posted one

Comment: The `HttpClient` is a single instance being reused by every request. All requests are also being made to the same domain. The 408 timeout is an error message sent by the server indicating the client failed to send the actual request after the initial handshake.

Comment: Your reply uses `await`, which isn't possible in synchronous code.

Comment: It is. You just change `await importer.Completion;` to `importer.Completion.Wait()`. That call should be done after posting all URLs to the head block. The blocks themselves won't block and `await` returns execution to the worker task, not the UI, so there's no risk of deadlocking. `AsyncContext` doesn't solve deadlocks automagically, it provides a different sync context to return to. That's just not needed with Dataflow blocks. In other code, `.ConfigureAwait(false)` avoids deadlocks by just not trying to return to any sync context.

Comment: In the end though, `AsyncContext` itself *will* block until its delegate completes.

Comment: You're right that the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is incorrect, I've removed that

Comment: Synchronous threads will block at `.Wait()` until the tasks are complete. Since both `Parallel.ForEach` and the default async context use the same threadpool, it's possible that all available threads could be blocking at `.Wait()` and none are available to actually perform the continuations, causing a deadlock. See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html. `AsyncContext` solves this by using a non-threadpool thread for the `async` code.

Comment: What do you mean `synchronous threads`? That's not what `AsyncContext ` does. Nor does `Wait` affect other threads. Threads don't have flavors. `Wait` blocks the calling thread only. If you use `async/await` in a desktop or old ASP.NET application, `await` will try to get back to that original thread/sync context. You get a deadlock if that thread/sync context is busy. As the linked article says, the solution is NOT using another thread, it's using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent returning to the original thread/context. What `AsyncContext` does is provide a different sync context

Comment: @SimonW why don't you just try using Dataflow? Even with 2 concurrent requests you'll see it doesn't behave the way you assume. If you make eg 100 posts it will still keep going. As for the actual 408 it may have nothing to do with `Wait()` but HttpClient bugs. 4.6 is *very* old and even 4.6.1 will go out of support in May 2022. There were some reports of unusual behavior way back when. Since the concurrent requests have already started there's no blocking issue due to `Wait()` itself. For some reason it's HttpClient itself that failed to continue

Comment: I need to call this synchronously, so I cannot use `await`, and `ConfigureAwait(false)` is only relevant when awaiting. I cannot use `.Wait()` or `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, because it would deadlock: when called in `Parallel.ForEach(...)`, all the threadpool threads would end up blocked there, and there would be none available to perform the continuations. See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/).

Comment: I'm using the AsyncEx library, linked at the end of [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), which provides `AsyncContext`. This type has a private synchronisation context which holds an instance of `AsyncContextThread`, which is not in the threadpool. This means that even if every threadpool thread is blocked at `AsyncContext.Run(...)`, the `AsyncContextThread` will still be executing continuations, so there cannot be a deadlock.

Comment: Using Dataflow inside an `AsyncContext` wouldn't provide any benefit compared to using `Task.WhenAll(...)` and a semaphore to restrict the number of simultaneous requests: it is still calling `await httpClient.SendAsync(...)` for multiple requests, and it still does not guarantee that any of those requests will be continued promptly enough to avoid timing out. If the first request has performed the handshake and is awaiting continuation there is nothing to ensure that task is prioritised over any another in the batch.

Comment: The 408 timeout cannot be related to `Wait()` because I am not using `Wait()`. It could be due to a bug in `HttpClient` in .NET Framework 4.6.2, but that is still supported until 2023.

Comment: But [you *are* using Wait](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs#L134). What `AsyncContext` does is [create a new synchronization context](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs#L51) so even if you forget `ConfigureAwait(false)` execution won't return to the root sync context. Those links are to the code of the very class you use